# How to rename the class or php file in laravel

Tags: laravel, rename

I Want to rename my php file so that wherever the name exists or used it's name for some functions in the whole laravel file that also should be changed by the new name.
How do i do that in laravel.?

Comment: Some IDEs such as PHPStorm support refactoring

Answer (score 2):

That's not a task for the Laravel framework. This is a task for your code editor, preferably an IDE like PHPStorm or NetBeans. Most IDEs have a function to refactor things like class names. In the case of PHPStorm you could right-click the class name you want to rename, select `Refactor->rename`. After that everything's self explanatory.

Comment: What is the real functionality of namespace in laravel ? is there any artisan command to do my doubt.